# How is it possible to add image(icon) as a string in the list?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

In a sample Xamarin essential code, I saw an image has been bound to the label as a string. How did they implement it?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can add FontAwesome or other icon-font and display the icons in Labels

Comment: Here is a article can refer to.(https://www.wintellect.com/using-fontawesome5-xamarin-forms/)